# PWA Best Practice: Web or Local Fonts?

Tags: caching, fonts, progressive-web-apps, preact

I am building a preact PWA (Progressive Web Application), and I do not know if I should keep fonts external to reduce my application size, or keep the fonts local to improve offline viewing? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update, Feb. 2021**: Browsers are generally moving in the direction of [partitioning the HTTP cache](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/10/http-cache-partitioning), meaning that CDN-like URLs, such as Google Fonts, are less likely to result in cache hits due to an unrelated web app having previously requesting the same URL. This eliminates a common argument in favor of using fonts from a CDN. A project like [fontsource](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource) can automate shipping a local copy of open source fonts, and while that's a bit more work, it's probably what I'd go with if you care the most about performance.*

I don't think that using web fonts hosted by a third-party or a first-party makes a difference based on what you're asking. It's possible to use the Cache Storage API inside of a service worker to cache either first- or third-party requests in general, including web font request, and make use of those cached resources while offline.

There are some general best practices for loading web fonts, and [this article](https://www.zachleat.com/web/comprehensive-webfonts/) by Zach Leatherman is my go-to reference. Those techniques aren't specific to building an offline-capable PWA, though.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to host font file amongst the root website files in folder `/fonts/`

We had to go with a font from https://www.dafont.com/ which provided a `.ttf` file, so will need to use any free converter tool to change that into a `.woff` file, in my case: https://convertio.co/ttf-woff/ helped out.

Then declare the new font in your CSS and use where needed:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Custom Font';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    /* Read next point */
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
    /* Download only latin glyphs */
    src:    local('Custom Font'),
            url('/fonts/custom-font.woff') format('woff');
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: 'Custom Font', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}
```

Our PWA needs a service worker to store files locally for offline mode, so with JS we call `service-worker.js`, which is located at root of website files:

```js
// When document is ready.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Steps followed from Google developer codelabs:
    // https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/offline/#5
    var registerServiceWorker = function registerServiceWorker() {
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
        }
    }

    registerServiceWorker();
});
```

and in our `/service-worker.js` for a basic website all this file needed:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open('my-website-name').then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/favicon.ico',
                '/manifest.json',
                '/fonts/custom-font.woff',
                '/images/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png',
                '/images/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png',
                '/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png',
                '/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png',
                '/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png',
                '/images/favicon/maskable_icon.png',
                '/images/favicon/monochrome_icon.png'
            ]);
        })
    );
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Make sure for this `/service-worker.js` file, that you update `my-website-name`, and also update the `cache.addAll` array by adding ALL other website files that your PWA requires to work properly offline.

That's basically all the code references for loading a custom font file for your PWA.